# NestJs - Unable to get user context in RolesGuard

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I'm using NestJS as the framework for a client API.  Within the framework we are using a pretty standard Passport/JWT auth infrastructure that is working fine.  Our AuthGuard is firing when the bearer token is found and, in secure API endpoints, I can inject the HTTP context via '@Res() request' and get access to the 'request.user' property which contains the payload of my Jwt token.

On top of this we are attempting to implement a 'RolesGuard' in a very similar fashion to the sample code provided in the documentation and some of the sample projects on GitHub (none of which actually use this guard but they include it as a sample guard).

Our issue is that our AuthGuard fires and validates the Jwt token and THEN our RolesGuard fires but the request object it is passed does not have the user meta-data attached to the request.

The key code in our RolesGuard is:

```
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;

    if (!user) {
        return false;
    }
```

In the above snipped the user is always false.  Has anyone written a role/permission based guard in Nest that successfully gets access to the scope of the current user?  All the code is firing and everything appears registered correctly.

-Kevin

Answer (score 37):

Ultimately this appears to be an ordering issue with the guards and it doesn't look like it can be easily resolved (without the framework allowing some control over the ordering).

My hope was to register the RolesGuard globally but that causes it to be registered first and fire first.

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), RolesGuard)
@Roles('admin')
```

If I register it at the endpoint level and put it after the AuthGuard then it fires second and I get the user context I am expecting within the guard itself.  It isn't perfect but it works.

-Kevin

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. It works well enough and can explicitly order the guards.

Comment: It could be resolved through middleware and looking through metadata for method but I wouldn't bother...

Comment: could this be solved using express sessions? Or is that not a good approach?

Comment: I find this answer to be perfectly acceptable and should solve 99% of use cases.

I'm assuming you were attempting to implement this logic as a **global** guard, which would execute before your JWT auth guard (assuming it's registered at the controller or route level). View the request lifecycle [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#summary). 

The order: Global guards -> Controller guards -> Route guards

Answer (score 9):

Make your RolesGuard extend AuthGuard('StrategyName') and then call super.canActivate for example:

```
@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {

        // call AuthGuard in order to ensure user is injected in request
        const baseGuardResult = await super.canActivate(context);
        if(!baseGuardResult){
            // unsuccessful authentication return false
            return false;
        }

        // successfull authentication, user is injected
        const {user} = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    }
}
```

In other words you have to Authenticate first then Authorize

Comment: hello it solve my problem but in that case when use try to login it gives 401 ... do you know how can i solve this problem .

Comment: @MahmudulHassan 401 means Guard is working well but the user was not authenticated, you need to debug it and check what is the issue.

Answer (score 8):

register RoleGuard at the endpoint level and put it after the AuthGuard then it fires second and I get the user context I am expecting within the guard itself.
don't register RoleGuard at module causes it'll be registered first and fire first.

*.module.ts

```
imports: [],
  providers: [{provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: RolesGuard} ,],  // remove guard
  controllers: [],
  exports: [],
```

Comment: Define the   @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), RolesGuard) and removed from module provider, works for me. Thanks

Comment: Removing it from the module provider worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else stumbles across this question: putting multiple guards into one `@UseGuards` decorator works, but if you want to keep them separated (say, if you use a custom decorator), you can give the 2nd guard access to `req.user` by placing it **before** the `@UseGuards` call that puts the user on the request object, as in this example:

```
@RestrictTo(UserAuthorities.admin)
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Get("/your-route")
```

It seems that this is a consequence of [how decorators work in TypeScript](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/1567#issuecomment-731808138).

Comment: Thanks for this 1-year-old answer. My code finally works :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use multiple roles for role-based Authentication.

In UserController

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Post,
  UseGuards,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RolesGuard } from 'src/guards/auth.guard';

@UseGuards(new RolesGuard(['admin']))
@Controller()
export class UserController { ... }
```

In RolesGuard

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ExecutionContextHost } from '@nestjs/core/helpers/execution-context-host';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private roles: string[] | null) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const { req } = ctx.getContext();
    return super.canActivate(new ExecutionContextHost([req]));
  }

  handleRequest(err: any, user: any, info: string) {
    if (!this.roles) {
      return user || null;
    }

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Not Valid User.');
    }

    const role = user.role;
    const doesRoleMatch = this.roles.some(r => r === role);
    if (!doesRoleMatch) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Not Valid User.');
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```